# How to implement DIV for this table structure

Tags: asp.net, html, css

[image]

I am trying to replicate this table structure by using div.

```
<asp:Table ID="tblAnnualReportServiceForm" runat="server" Width="100%" CellSpacing="1" CellPadding="5">
    <asp:TableRow >
        <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server" CellSpacing="1" CellPadding="5">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" Width="130px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow >
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" Text="End Date"></asp:Label>
                    </asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" Width="130px" style="text-align:left" ValidationGroup="MKE" />
                    </asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>             
            </asp:Table>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

I have tried the following DIV and I haven't have much CSS experience.

```
<div>
    <div  style="float:left">
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Start Date"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="130px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   </div>    
   <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="End Date"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="130px" style="text-align:left" ValidationGroup="MKE" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Any pointers would be of great help. I have too many table structure that needs to be converted to DIV. I appreciate the help

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a legitimate table structure? Does it not contain tabular data? I wouldn't recommend turning it into DIV soup just for the sake of it not being a `<table>`

Comment: @ Pekka - I thought of leaving it as is and code review comment was to use DIV instead of table for layouts. Thanks!

Comment: @kalls How many columns/rows do you think it takes to be tabular data?  Dumping tabular data into divs is just as bad as using tables for layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
        <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" Width="130px" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
        <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblEndDate" runat="server" Text="End Date"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:50%;">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" Width="130px" style="text-align:left" ValidationGroup="MKE" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want to get some paddings/margins you can add another div into a cell div:

```
<div style="float:left;width:50%;">
    <div style="border:solid 1px black;padding:5px;margin:1px;">                
            <asp:Label ID="lblStartDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jGkxJ/) or [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jGkxJ/2/) is a demo with classes (using `style` is not a very good idea, so I created few classes and removed styles from div tags)

Comment: Thank you this is close to my layout but when I change the width percentage to 20% the whole layout changes.

Comment: See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jGkxJ/3/) demo. It has new class, `row`, and cell width set to 20%

Comment: Updated answer to reflect `row` class styles from the latest demo

Answer (score 2):

A general structure to replicate table is like.

```
<!--table-->
<div>
        <!--tr-->
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <!--td-->
                <div style="float:left">
                </div>
                <!--td-->
                <div style="float:right">
                </div>
        <!--tr-->
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <!--td-->
                <div style="float:left">
                </div>
                <!--td-->
                <div style="float:right">
                </div>
        <!--tr-->
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: - Thanks, I will use this as future reference.

Comment: great! div's are more fast to render, but sometimes difficult to manage. once you are master of it, you will use it always. use table when you have to use tabular data, and use div when you have to design layout.

Answer (score 0):

Check out:

1.) **[YUI Grids](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/grids/)** - for **Tableless design**

The foundational YUI Grids CSS offers four preset page widths, six preset templates, and the ability to stack and nest subdivided regions of two, three, or four columns. The 4kb file provides over 1000 page layout combinations.

2.) [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/):  The premise of the system is ideally suited to rapid prototyping, but it would work equally well when integrated into a production environment. There are printable sketch sheets, design layouts, and a CSS file that have identical measurements.

Comment: I appreciate this! I need to go through an approval process to use this. Currently, I can only do code changes. I will have this in mind. Thank you!

Comment: @kalls The most important thing is that by using these CSS framework most of the cross-browser issues can be avoided.